# C: Passing an array into a function 'on the fly'

Tags: c, arrays, parameter-passing

I have a function, and I want to pass an array of char* to it, but I don't want to create a variable just for doing that, like this:

```
char *bar[]={"aa","bb","cc"};
foobar=foo(bar);
```

To get around that, I tried this:

```
foobar=foo({"aa","bb","cc"});
```

But it doesn't work. I also tried this:

```
foobar=foo("aa\0bb\0cc");
```

It compiles with a warning and if I execute the program, it freezes.
I tried playing a bit with asterisks and ampersands too but I couldn't get it to work properly.

Is it even possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, you can use a compound literal.  Note that you will need to provide some way for the function to know the length of the array.  One is to have a NULL at the end.

```
foo((char *[]){"aa","bb","cc",NULL});
```

This feature was added in C99.

Comment: And therefore probably isn't available if the compiler is MSVC.

Answer (score 7):

You need to declare the type for your compound literal:

```
foobar = foo((char *[]){"aa", "bb", "cc"});
```

Answer (score 1):

Some times variable arguments are sufficient:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void func(int n, ...)
{
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, n);
  while (n--)
  {
    const char *e = va_arg(args, const char *);
    printf("%s\n", e);
  }
  va_end(args);
}

int main()
{
  func(3, "A", "B", "C");
  return 0;
}
```

But I generally prefer the method suggested by Matthew and Carl.