# How to pass a temporary array to a function in standard C++17

Tags: c++, arrays, parameter-passing, c++17, temporary

I have a function of the following signature:

```cpp
void foo(int argc, char const * const argv[]);
```

I would like to call it in a concise way, similar, but not necessary identical as below:

```cpp
foo(3, {"one", "two", "three"});
```

I know that C supports compound literals just for this purpose ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744117/c-passing-an-array-into-a-function-on-the-fly)).

I also know how to solve the problem using templates ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42332229/how-to-pass-a-temporary-array)).

However, my problem is slightly different. The function signature is fixed - it normally takes arguments passed to `main` and the size of the array is not predefined. I am writing tests for this function and in my case the passed arrays are known at compile-time.

Is there a way to call `foo` without using temporary variables or wrapper functions like below?

```cpp
char const * array[3] = {"one", "two", "three"};
foo(3, array);
```

```cpp
template<int N>
void wrapper(char const * const (&array)[N])
{
    foo(N, array);
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend changing the function to take a `std::array` or `std::vector`. That's going to make your life simpler.

Comment: @JesperJuhl And how do you pass `argc` and `argv` to a `std::array`? You can't. I already have a wrapper that takes `std::vector`, but I would like to eliminate it if possible.

Comment: Isn't this a case for an `initializer_list`?

Comment: @alle_meije Not really, at least not without another wrapper function that would forward the call to `foo`.

Comment: @KrzysiekKarbowiak: Why wouldn't you want to use the C++ wrapper you wrote? It's a much better interface as you are not allowed to *lie* about the size of the array. The size of the array given to the underlying function will always be correct.

Comment: Have you tried `enable_if<true, char const*[]>::type{"one", "two", "three"}`? Why wouldn't it work?

Comment: In Standardization of C++11, during the final days I had some good arguments for allowing array temporaries, and together with http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#1058 and http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1232 , they were allowed from C++11 onwards.

Comment: GCC raises an error about "taking the adress of a temporary array", but according to http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.array, both lvalue and rvalue arrays can be implicitly converted to pointers. So I'm unsure why GCC rejects. Clang accepts!

Comment: @NicolBolas: My `foo` function is used to parse command-line arguments and as such it is called with what `main` gets. In this case there is little place for errors or lies. I am writing unit tests for `foo` and would like to use the interface directly (and make the `std::vector` overload private). I am also somewhat disappointed that I can to it in C but not in C++.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: I also noticed this difference between GCC and Clang. Later on I will check how MSVC behaves.

Comment: @KrzysiekKarbowiak: "*I am writing unit tests for foo and would like to use the interface directly*" If you're writing unit tests for it, why is it so important to use the interface directly? I mean, you said "there is little place for errors or lies", so you're *not* testing what happens if your sizes don't match your arrays. So, isn't it important for your unit tests to be unable to accidentally mismatch the sizes with the strings?

Comment: @NicolBolas: In my code `foo(int, char * [])` calls `foo(std::vector<char const *>)`. Both overloads are public. My unit tests call the `std::vector` overload out of convenience. It means that while they cannot mismatch the sizes with the strings, the won't detect any errors in constructing the vector in the first overload. If I can call the first overload directly and conveniently, I can make the `std::vector` overload private and get better coverage.

Comment: Also it seems unclear what you're asking.  The braced list of string literals is not a valid initializer for pointer-to-pointer,  however you say you do not want to make any of the changes that would supply a valid initializer

Comment: Note that `main` expects a sentinel null pointer in `argv` (although of course it can always use `argc` for that purpose instead).

Comment: @M.M: OK, I see the question is not as clear as I thought. Let me edit.

Comment: `std::span` in C++20 would probably make it much easier

Answer (score 2):

though I have no idea how compiler works, it works:

```
template<size_t N>
void foo(int argc, const char *(&&argv)[N]){
    int i=0;
    for( auto o: argv) {
        ++i;
        cout<<"array"<<i<<" = " << o<<"\n";
    }

    cout<< "\narray size "<<i<<"\n"<<argc<<"\n";
    return;
}

int main(){

    foo(3, {"one", "two", "three"});

}

array1 = one
array2 = two
array3 = three

array size 3
3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple wrapper for arguments themselves.

<s>Example</s> (see below):

```
auto wrapper(std::initializer_list<const char*> lst) {
    return lst.begin();
}

foo(3, wrapper({"one", "two", "three"}));
```

This solution requires that `initializer_list` be destroyed when `foo()` returns. The moment when it is destroy is [implementation-defined](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.call#7.sentence-9):

> It is implementation-defined whether the lifetime of a parameter ends when the function in which it is defined returns or at the end of the enclosing full-expression.

Thanks **NathanOliver** for pointing that out.

---

**Edit.** After the discussion that followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62165932), it seems that the code above can easily be fixed by passing the `initializer_list` by reference, not by value, i.e.:

```
auto wrapper(const std::initializer_list<const char*>& lst) {
    return lst.begin();
}

foo(3, wrapper({"one", "two", "three"}));
```

Now the temporary `initializer_list` is [guaranteed to exist](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#4.sentence-3) until `foo()` returns:

> Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression that (lexically) contains the point where they were created.

Thanks **cdhowie** for clarifications.